# Lucene: Filtering for documents NOT containing a Term

Tags: java, search, filter, lucene

I have an index whose documents have two fields (actually more like 800 fields but the other fields won't concern us here):

- The `contents` field contains the analyzed/tokenized text of the document. The query string is searched for in this field.
- The `category` field contains the single category identifier of the document. There are about 2500 different categories, and a document may occur in several of them (i.e. a document may have multiple `category` entries. The results are filtered by this field.

The index contains about 20 mio. documents and is 5 GB in size.

The index is queried with a user-provided query string, plus an optional set of a few categories the user is *not* interested in. **The question is**: how can I remove those documents matching not only the query string but also the unwanted categories.

I could use a `BooleanQuery` with a `MUST_NOT` clause, i.e. something like this:

```
BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery();
q.add(contentQuery, BooleanClause.MUST);
for (String unwanted: unwantedCategories) {
    q.add(new TermsQuery(new Term("category", unwanted), BooleanClause.MUST_NOT);
}
```

Is there a way to do this with Lucene filters? Performance is an issue here, and there will only be a few, recurring, variants of `unwantedCategories`, so a `CachingWrapperFilter` would probably help a lot. Also, due to the way the Lucene queries are generated in the existing code base, it is difficult to fit this in, whereas an extra `Filter` could be introduced easily.

In other words, **How do I create a `Filter` based on what terms *must* _not_ occur in a document?**

Comment: @ajreal: I'm not using the Lucene analyzer; which AFAIK generates queries anyway, not filters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One word answer: **`BooleanFilter`**, found it minutes after formulating the question:

```
BooleanFilter f = new BooleanFilter();
for (String unwanted: unwantedCategories) {
    TermsFilter tf = new TermsFilter(new Term("category", unwanted));
    f.add(new FilterClause(tf, BooleanClause.MUST_NOT));
}
```

Comment: I am having similar issue. My filter is not working at all for TextValues. Filter LEA = new QueryWrapperFilter(new TermQuery(new Term(field, "0401000"))); I have created a question on Stack Overflow it will be great if yu can adderss it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906689/filter-not-working-with-text-values-lucene-3-0-3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [QueryWrapperFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/QueryWrapperFilter.html) to turn an arbitrary query into a filter. And you can use a [CachingWrapperFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/CachingWrapperFilter.html) to cache any filter. So something like:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
// set up bq
Filter myFilter = new CachingWrapperFilter (
                     new QueryWrapperFilter (bq)
                  );
```